# GoDaddy Subdomain to Heroku Api with SSL

Tags: ssl, heroku, shared-hosting

I'm trying to get my api hosted on Heroku, to be assigned to a subdomain from GoDaddy hosting.

Here's what I have setup:
The CNAME on GoDaddy:
[image]

And my heroku domains:
[image]

And when I try to browser a GET endpoint:
[image]

I'm using a development Heroku account, which comes with a free automatic ssl cert. I am pretty new to SSL certs, is there anything on need to do on the GoDaddy side besides setup the CNAME?

If I redirect to "imbibe-now.herokuapp.com", the api works, but without https.

Any tips would be appreciated!